# Added a IBOutlet and Custom TableViewCell doesn't work anymore

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I just added a `IBOutlet` to my `UIImageView` in my Storyboard and now my Custom `TableViewCell` does not work anymore.

```
2012-08-13 13:30:28.052 Project[6189:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TableViewController 0x808ab80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.'


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
static NSString *CellNib = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
...
}
```

Any Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my app look. I use Dynamic Prototyping Table and custom cells.

[image: ss]

My storyboard is like below.

[image: ss]

The point is that you should set **tag** of image view as below.

[image: ss]

Don't forget to set the **cell identifier** same with that in code. And the code is below:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"];
```

Comment: My TableViewCell is Custom. Higher, 10 Labels,4 Pictures.
UILabel Outlets are working. UIImageView not. This was my Question.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your situation. Now I show a part of my app. I wish this help you.

Comment: Thanks this works.
But i still dont understand why i cannot use a IBOutlet for a UIImageView. This is confusing

Comment: In my experience, when using storyboard, [[UIImage alloc] init...] doesn't work at all. I think the storyboard might initialize image view. This is convenient, but difficult to understand.